# Digitizing geological information with MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, digitizing, geology

Due to vast information included in a geological map, I really need to find a way to digitize some features (mostly lines) in a rapid way.

"Click-by-click" method will cost me some millions of years in time.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way in MapInfo but you can download the freely available Orfeo Toolbox. It has many tools such as Feature Extraction and Image Segmentation that might help create Line Vectors from your geologic image.